# Mysql View are slow then sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, view

I Converted Sql View to mysql View using MYsql Workbench and ran it, but unfortunately my view is slow.

**These are my System requirements for MySql**.
Windows 10
Xampp V3.2.4
Php 7.3.12
Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
MYsql Workbench 8.0

**These are my System requirements for SqlServer**.
Windows 10
sql server 2005

**Results with images**
[sql server result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCKXJ.png)
[mysql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RugmI.png) 
**This is Mysql Query**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `hrms_v_attendancedetails_current_prev` AS
    SELECT 
        `e`.`compID` AS `compID`,
        `e`.`compName` AS `compName`,
        `e`.`compAddress` AS `compAddress`,
        `e`.`empAtt` AS `empAtt`,
        `ad`.`attDate` AS `attDate`,
        `e`.`empID` AS `empID`,
        `e`.`empExists` AS `empExists`,
        `e`.`empNo` AS `empNo`,
        `e`.`empDOJ` AS `empDOJ`,
        `e`.`empName` AS `empName`,
        `e`.`empBasicSalary` AS `BP`,
        `e`.`empHrsMonth` AS `empHrsMonth`,
        `e`.`empDaysMonth` AS `empDaysMonth`,
        `e`.`empEPFNo` AS `empEPFNo`,
        `e`.`empNameFull` AS `empNameFull`,
        `e`.`empSex` AS `empSex`,
        `e`.`etID` AS `etID`,
        `e`.`etName` AS `etName`,
        `e`.`sup_desigID` AS `sup_desigID`,
        `e`.`desigName` AS `desigName`,
        `e`.`sup_empID` AS `sup_empID`,
        `e`.`vacID` AS `vacID`,
        `e`.`intvID` AS `intvID`,
        `e`.`empDOEntitlement` AS `empDOEntitlement`,
        `e`.`empProbationPeriod` AS `empProbationPeriod`,
        `e`.`empGraceTime` AS `empGraceTime`,
        `e`.`empPaymentMode` AS `empPaymentMode`,
        `e`.`actID` AS `actID`,
        `e`.`actName` AS `actName`,
        `e`.`cityID` AS `cityID`,
        `e`.`div_cityID` AS `div_cityID`,
        `e`.`empAddress` AS `empAddress`,
        `e`.`empTempAddress` AS `empTempAddress`,
        `e`.`empRoute` AS `empRoute`,
        `e`.`empContPerson` AS `empContPerson`,
        `e`.`empTempContPerson` AS `empTempContPerson`,
        `e`.`empPhoneM` AS `empPhoneM`,
        `e`.`empPhoneH` AS `empPhoneH`,
        `e`.`empTempPhoneH` AS `empTempPhoneH`,
        `e`.`empEmail` AS `empEmail`,
        `e`.`empDOB` AS `empDOB`,
        `e`.`empIDCardNo` AS `empIDCardNo`,
        `e`.`empComments` AS `empComments`,
        `e`.`empInsuranceNo` AS `empInsuranceNo`,
        `e`.`empPayroll` AS `empPayroll`,
        `e`.`empMachineID` AS `empMachineID`,
        `e`.`empLastExitedDate` AS `empLastExitedDate`,
        `e`.`deptName` AS `deptName`,
        `ad`.`adInTime` AS `adInTime`,
        `ad`.`adOutTime` AS `adOutTime`,
        `ad`.`adOT` AS `OT`,
        `ad`.`adDOT` AS `DOT`,
        `ad`.`adTOT` AS `TOT`,
        `ad`.`adOTMin` AS `OTMin`,
        `ad`.`adDOTMin` AS `DOTMin`,
        `ad`.`adTOTMin` AS `TOTMin`,
        `ad`.`adLateTime` AS `adLateTime`,
        `ad`.`adShortTime` AS `adShortTime`,
        `ad`.`adEarlyTime` AS `adEarlyTime`,
        `ad`.`adLateTime` + `ad`.`adShortTime` + `ad`.`adEarlyTime` AS `LM`,
        `e`.`empAutoPresent` AS `empAutoPresent`,
        `ad`.`adDateStatus` AS `adDateStatus`,
        IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`) AS `adDateStatus_1`,
        CASE
            WHEN
                (LEFT(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                    2) = 'HX'
                    AND LOCATE('+',
                        IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)) > 0)
            THEN
                SUBSTR(`ad`.`adDateStatus`,
                    1,
                    LOCATE(`ad`.`adDateStatus`, '+') - 1) + '+' + SUBSTR(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                    LOCATE(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                    `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                            '+') + 1,
                    5)
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    (RIGHT(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                        2) = 'HX'
                        AND LOCATE('+',
                            IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                    `ad`.`adDateStatus`)) > 0)
                THEN
                    SUBSTR(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                        1,
                        LOCATE(IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`),
                                '+') - 1) + '+' + SUBSTR(`ad`.`adDateStatus`,
                        LOCATE(`ad`.`adDateStatus`, '+') + 1,
                        2)
                ELSE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            END
        END AS `adDateStatus_ReadOnly`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'P' THEN 1
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HP'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA+HP'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HP+HA'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)+HX'
                        AND `ad`.`adDateStatus` = 'HA+HP'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HX+HL(p)')
                THEN
                    0.5
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS `P`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA+HP'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HP+HA'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)+HX'
                        AND `ad`.`adDateStatus` = 'A'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HX+HL(p)'
                        AND `ad`.`adDateStatus` = 'A')
                THEN
                    0.5
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS `A`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'A' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `FA`,
        CASE
            WHEN
                (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA+HP'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HP+HA'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)+HA'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HA+HL(p)')
            THEN
                1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `HA`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'L(p)' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `FL(p)`,
        CASE
            WHEN
                (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)+HX'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)'
                    OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HX+HL(p)')
            THEN
                1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `HL(p)`,
        CASE
            WHEN
                IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                        `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(l)'
            THEN
                0.5
            ELSE 0
        END AS `HL(l)`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'L(p)' THEN 1
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)+HX'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(p)'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HX+HL(p)')
                THEN
                    0.5
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS `L(p)`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'L(l)' THEN 1
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    (IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(l)+HX'
                        OR IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HX+HL(l)')
                THEN
                    0.5
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS `L(l)`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'L(n)' THEN 1
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN
                    IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                            `ad`.`adDateStatus`) = 'HL(n)+HX'
                THEN
                    0.5
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS `L(n)`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'SL' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `SL`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'H' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `H`,
        CASE IFNULL(`adl`.`ladDateStatus`,
                `ad`.`adDateStatus`)
            WHEN 'DF' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS `DF`,
        `e`.`deptID` AS `deptID`,
        `e`.`desigID` AS `desigID`,
        `ad`.`adInTime_Prev` AS `adIntime_Prev`,
        `ad`.`adOutTime_Prev` AS `adOutTime_Prev`,
        `ad`.`adssID_Prev` AS `adSSID_Prev`,
        `ad`.`adOTApproved_Prev` AS `adOTApproved_Prev`,
        `adl`.`ltName` AS `ltName`,
        `adl`.`ltID` AS `ltID`,
        `e`.`desigNoofAllotedEmps` AS `desigNoofAllotedEmps`,
        `adl`.`ltFrequency` AS `ltFrequency`,
        `adl`.`eltNOD` AS `eltNOD`,
        `cd`.`htID` AS `htID`,
        `e`.`deptCode` AS `deptCode`,
        `e`.`desigCode` AS `desigCode`,
        `ad`.`adPunch_2` AS `adPunch_2`,
        `ad`.`adPunch_3` AS `adPunch_3`,
        `ad`.`adPunch_4` AS `adPunch_4`,
        `ad`.`adPunch_5` AS `adPunch_5`,
        `ad`.`adEarlyOTApproved` AS `adEarlyOTApproved`,
        `ad`.`adOTApproved` AS `adOTApproved`,
        `ht`.`htName` AS `htName`,
        `ht`.`htType` AS `htType`,
        `e`.`compSysCompany` AS `compSysCompany`,
        `e`.`compEmail` AS `compEmail`,
        `e`.`compPhoneNo` AS `compPhoneNo`,
        `e`.`egraID` AS `egraID`,
        `e`.`egraCode` AS `egraCode`,
        `e`.`egraName` AS `egraName`,
        `ad`.`adLunch` AS `adLunch`,
        `ad`.`adDinner` AS `adDinner`,
        `ad`.`adLunch_Prev` AS `adLunch_Prev`,
        `ad`.`adDinner_Prev` AS `adDinner_Prev`,
        `e`.`relID` AS `relID`,
        `e`.`relName` AS `relName`,
        `e`.`empEarlyOT` AS `empEarlyOT`,
        `ad`.`adRemarks` AS `adRemarks`,
        `e`.`pgID` AS `pgID`,
        `e`.`subID` AS `subID`,
        `ad`.`created_by` AS `created_by`,
        `ad`.`created_at` AS `created_at`,
        `ad`.`edited_by` AS `edited_by`,
        `ad`.`updated_at` AS `updated_at`,
        `ad`.`ssID` AS `ssID`,
        `ad`.`ssName` AS `ssName`,
        `ad`.`ssType` AS `ssType`,
        `ad`.`ssFromTime` AS `ssFromTime`,
        `ad`.`ssToTime` AS `ssToTime`
    FROM
        (((`hrms_v_employee` `e`
        JOIN `hrms_v_attendancedetails` `ad` ON (`e`.`compID` = `ad`.`compID`
            AND `e`.`empID` = `ad`.`empID`))
        LEFT JOIN (`hrms_tbl_holidaytype` `ht`
        JOIN `hrms_tbl_calendardetails` `cd` ON (`ht`.`compID` = `cd`.`compID`
            AND `ht`.`htID` = `cd`.`htID`)) ON (`ad`.`compID` = `cd`.`compID`
            AND `ad`.`attDate` = `cd`.`caldetDate`))
        LEFT JOIN `hrms_v_attendancedetails_leave` `adl` ON (`ad`.`compID` = `adl`.`compID`
            AND `ad`.`attDate` = `adl`.`ladDate`
            AND `ad`.`empID` = `adl`.`empID`))
    WHERE
        `ad`.`attDate` >= '11/01/2011'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` from the views underlying table in text form. Also include `EXPLAIN {query}` in text from. Edit the question as required. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Note `ad.attDate >= '11/01/2011': The mysql date format is YYYYMMDD so this condition isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: thank you for your reply i am new one for this form and sorry for my mistake.`ad`.`attDate`>="2019-08-01" is this wrong how to type that?

Comment: Right its: `YYYY-MM-DD`. Still missing other requested information.

Comment: thank you @RickJames , i fixed it but also query get 3.172sec/125.985.

Comment: And the `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @BmtMadushanka As Rick suggests above... please provide the result of EXPLAIN.
To run it... simply run the query as follows
EXPLAIN SELECT 
       `e`.`compID` AS `compID`,...
       ...
put your entire Select query preceded by explain and give us the screenshot. 
You may be missing some indexes, keys, relations (if innodb). Minor modifications to tables might significantly speed up your view (x10 ~ x300 even)

Comment: @AngelosHadjiphilippou thank you for your reply i fixed my problem.the reason is i froget give a index in one table.after do that query is speed.